# Problem with Installing Fedora 24 with Anaconda

Tags: fedora, system-installation, macintosh, installer-anaconda

I am trying to install Fedora 24 (Workstation) with Anaconda using the .iso file I downloaded from the Fedora website on my MacBook Air.

The disk I want to install Fedora onto is an external SSD which has two existing partitions. I selected automatic partitioning and freed up 120 GB of free space on that SSD after being prompted to reclaim space. However, I keep getting the error message `failed to find a suitable stage1 device`. I've tried rebooting my computer but the same error persists.

Does the problem lie with my SSD or is it due to some other reason? How can I resolve this?